# Get fields with index instead name of column in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Someone knows how to access the plsql oracle cursor fields through an index.

Is it possible to get the fields of the table through an index instead of the name of column?

Thanks in advance.

```
declare
  cursor c_user is 
    select * 
      from users
     where age > 20;
begin
    for u in c_user loop
        dbms_output.put_line(u.lastname||' '||u.firstname);
    end loop; 
end;
```

Example

```
declare
  cursor c_user is 
    select * 
      from users
     where age > 20;
begin
    for u in c_user loop
        dbms_output.put_line(u.1||' '||u.2);
    end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It sounds like you might be  looking for an approach that [uses `dbms_sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42563100/266304), but without knowing why you don't want to use column names, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can refer to the fields in a PL/SQL record by their position, the answer is no. You can only refer to them by name.

By the way, in the database world, an *index* usually refers to a database object that stores key values from a table together with their physical location organised for fast retrieval, and a *table* is, oh never mind, so *"get the fields of the table through an index"* had me a bit confused because I don't think you mean an optimised lookup of stored data. Apologies if I have this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
declare
cursor Inx_Cur(P_Indx Number) is select 
decode(P_Indx,1,ACCOUNTNO,2,ACCOUNTNAME,3,ACCOUNTTYPE) My_field
from accounts;
begin
for Rec in Inx_Cur(3) -- pass the required index as 
parameter
loop
 dbms_output.put_line('My_field : '||Rec.My_field);
end loop;
end;
```